# Package not loading correctly

Tags: r

I am trying to load the forecast package and when giving the command library(forecast) it returns this.

```
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: timeDate
This is forecast 5.6 

Warning message:
package ‘timeDate’ was built under R version 3.1.2
```

I don't understand what the issue is here. I have installed zoo, timeDate, and forecast and it seemed like it was successful. Let me know if you need more information to help.

Answer (score 6):

You're just getting warnings, not errors. Sounds like one of the dependent packages was just built with an earlier version of R. try running `update.packages()` to update potentially out of date packages.

Comment: More like that this user is running 3.1.1 or earlier (especially since version 3.1.2 just came out this week). That is the warning that I see when a package is built with a later (minor) version.

Comment: looks like I am using 3.1.1. So do you think these warnings are causing problems with some of the package's functions? Or do you think everything should be working in order? I am new to R and it's a little hard for me to tell if it's working as expected...

Comment: After updating to 3.1.2 the "Warning message:" does not appear but the zoo related info is the same.

Comment: @AlphaCentauriAB That is a message (not a warning or error) about package NAMESPACE exports. zoo is exporting functions that have the same names as those included in a base package, so when you call those functions you will get the zoo versions rather than the base versions.